# Creating a histogram using custom data

Tags: histograms

Let's consider the following simple data set

```
data = {{0,1.48},{1,0},{2.3,6.22},{3.1,0.01},{3.45,2.66},{5.34,0.11},
        {7.98,3.18},{8.12,4.11},{8.32,0},{9.65,3.56},{10,5.22}};
```

The list contains pairs $(x,y)$. I want to use this data for creating a histogram where the $x$ values are the horizontal values of the histogram, while the corresponding $y$ values indicate the height of the respective bar of the histogram. I also should be able to control the width of the bars, let's say to be equal to 0.001.

Any suggestions on how to create the desired histogram?

Comment: are the x values mid-points of bins or bin widths?

Comment: @kglr Well, the x values are the central values of the bins. However, I need to be able to control the width of the bin, let's say to be equal to 0.001.

Comment: related : [Histogram based on pre-binned data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/188230/125)

Comment: @kglr `ListPlot` is not what I want. What I want is a real histogram where I can control the width of the boxes.

Comment: You don't have a histogram.  A histogram is constructed from "counts" from a sample of observations.  There is no evidence that the $y$ values are related to counts in any way.  Also, if the bins are already chosen, you certainly can't create smaller bin widths.  Are the heights related to frequencies or means or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just convert your data to `WeightedData` with `WeightedData @@ Transpose[data]`:

```
Histogram[WeightedData @@ Transpose[data], 10]
```

Comment: What is the purpose of 10 inside the histogram commend?

Comment: That just tells `Histogram` how many bins to use. You can specify the bins in a variety of ways. `Automatic` will leave `Histogram` to figure it out for you, but it doesn't always do a very good job. Specifying an integer like `10` tells it to use 10 bins. If you want to specify the bin width explicitly, you can use `{width}` (e.g., `{1}` for bins 1 unit wide).

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
width = 0.1;
{x, y} = Transpose@{{0, 1.48}, {1, 0}, {2.3, 6.22}, {3.1, 
     0.01}, {3.45, 2.66}, {5.34, 0.11}, {7.98, 3.18}, {8.12, 
     4.11}, {8.32, 0}, {9.65, 3.56}, {10, 5.22}};

Graphics[{Lighter@Blue, 
  Table[Rectangle[{x[[i]], 0}, {x[[i]] + width, y[[i]]}], {i, 
    Length@x}]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Or

```
width = 0.1;
data = {{0, 1.48}, {1, 0}, {2.3, 6.22}, {3.1, 0.01}, {3.45, 
    2.66}, {5.34, 0.11}, {7.98, 3.18}, {8.12, 4.11}, {8.32, 0}, {9.65,
     3.56}, {10, 5.22}};
Graphics[{Lighter@Blue, 
  Rectangle[{#1, 0}, {#1 + width, #2}] & @@@ data}, Frame -> True]
```